# Ruby join array of strings with space between last two elements

Tags: ruby

In my Ruby 2.7 app I want to join an array of strings to have one string separated by commas. As follows:

```
[company.name, company.street, company.zipcode, company.city]
=> ["Sanford, Reilly and Schmidt", "Hoffmannstr. 186", "84875", "Gebesee"]
```

Expected result:

```
["Sanford, Reilly and Schmidt", "Hoffmannstr. 186", "84875 Gebesee"]
```

Obviously to have such a result I can put an empty string between `company.zipcode` and `company.city` and at the end use `.join(', ')` method like this:

```
[company.name, company.street, company.zipcode + ' ' + company.city].join(', ')
```

But honestly this code is smelly for me, is there any better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Well one way to make it less "smelly" is do not use `+` to concatenate Strings. Instead use interpolation `[company.name, company.street, "#{company.zipcode} #{company.city}"].join(', ')`

Comment: The Facets gem has all kinds of interesting methods. [Array#conjoin](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/facets/Array#conjoin-instance_method) is one of them; it is like `join` but more powerful. It allows for a second argument (and/or a block): `[1,2,3].conjoin(', ', ' and ') # =>"1, 2 and 3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two `join()` calls:

```
[company.name, company.street, [company.zipcode, company.city].join(' ')].join(', ')
```

This method is preferred if you have non-blank delimiter on which to join and/or an array argument. In your specific case, the solution by *engineersmnky* using `"#{...} #{...}"` is shorter and more clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [company.name, company.street, company.zipcode, company.city]
  #=> ["Sanford, Reilly and Schmidt", "Hoffmannstr. 186", "84875", "Gebesee"]
```

```
arr[0..-3] << "%s %s" % arr[-2, 2]
  #=> ["Sanford, Reilly and Schmidt", "Hoffmannstr. 186", "84875 Gebesee"]
```

or

```
arr[0..-3] << arr[-2, 2].join(' ')
  #=> ["Sanford, Reilly and Schmidt", "Hoffmannstr. 186", "84875 Gebesee"]
```

`arr` is not mutated.